# ViewController Delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

is it possible to access a ViewController's methods from the appDelegate, like it is possible inverse with the following code:?

```
AppDelegate *ad = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

When I try

```
ViewController *vc = (ViewController *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

I get an error...

Thanks!

Comment: You're getting an error because you're calling something a `ViewController` that's obviously **not** a `ViewController`.  (I say 'obviously' because it can't be one if it's already an `AppDelegate`.)  You can do something like what you want but the code depends on how the view controller is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

or if your delegate have properties

```
YourAppDelegate *ad = (YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
ViewController *vc = ad.yourViewControllerProperty;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `AppDelegate`, assuming `viewController` is your `rootViewController`, you can get a list of all view controllers on the stack by with:

```
NSLog(@"List of current active view controllers:%@", self.viewController.navController.viewControllers);
```

To access a specific view controller in the viewControllers:

```
[[self.viewController.navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i] someMethodOfThatViewController];
```